# Ruby native extensions: target and file names

Tags: ruby, ruby-native-extensions

I've written a few Ruby native extensions, the usual deal is to have a "target name", `foo` say, then have a file `ext/foo/foo.c` which defines `Init_foo`.  I have a need (see below) to have a different filename, `ext/foo/bar.c` say, which defines `Init_foo` instead.  Is this even possible?

*Why on Earth do this*

I have an existing Gem called `foo`, it wraps an existing C library `libfoo` which contains a file `foo.c`, both are stable and have users. I don't want users of the gem to have to install `libfoo` themselves, instead to have it embedded in the gem itself.  This is the "packaged source" strategy as described [here](https://github.com/flavorjones/ruby-c-extensions-explained#strategy-2a-packaged_source).  When trying to compile with this strategy I get errors about `foo.c` being duplicated (as it is).  If I could get the "extension file" renamed as above, that should remove this roadblock.

Comment: This case has been warned at the link you referred to in the "What can go wrong section". How costly would it be to change the name only in the packaged gem?

Comment: That would be pretty painful I think, it seems less so to rename the `foo.c` from the embedded library (MakeMakefile just uses a wildcard to generate the list of files to compile), it does add an extra step to the build (after copying in the library files) and feels a by grimy, but does at leas compile.